# Recursive function returns early only checking one path

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm creating a connect four game, and I am using recursion to check if the move made is a winning move. x and y are the co-ordinates of the move on the 7x6 grid.

I have yet to implement checking if the direction of the points matches up correctly (so right now if the 4 pieces are touching in any way, it should still detect a win). But before I do that I have run into a problem. Even though the move made should result in a win, if there is another path where there are not four in a row, the function returns false.

Example of function incorrectly not detecting a win (green line is what should have been detected, red line is the path I believe the function took to return false early): https://prnt.sc/fjhia1

This is my code:

```
function isVisited(x,y,visited){
    var pointStr = x + "," + y;
    var result = visited.some(function(e){
      return e.join() == pointStr;
    });
    return result;
}

function checkWin(x, y, color, visited, count) {
    if(count==3) return true;
    for(i=-1; i<2; i++) {
        for (j=-1; j<2; j++) {
            if(!(i==0 && j==0) && (x+i)<7 && (y+j)<6 && (x+i)>-1 && (y+j)>-1 && grid[x+i][y+j] != null) {
                if (grid[x+i][y+j] == color && !isVisited(x+i,y+j,visited)) {
                    visited.push([x, y]);
                    if(checkWin(x+i, y+j, color, visited, count+1)) return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

To clarify, the i and the j are offsets used to check all the points around the starting point.

The color parameter is either "black" or "red". The grid is a 7x6 2D array, which stores which players pieces are where, and is updated when a player makes a move. The whole checkWin() function is called after every move, with x and y arguments being the co-ordinates of the move just played. An example of colors in the array is shown in the picture linked.

Grid sample from the image, this should return true when passed into checkWin() at x=5, y=3, color="black", but it doesn't:

```
[[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,"black"],[null,null,null,null,"black","red"],[null,null,null,"black","black","black"],[null,null,null,"red","red","red"]]
```

Comment: What does `isVisited` do? Don't you want to use the local `visited`? (That's not being passed into `isVisited`.)

Comment: Oops! I forgot to pass it into the array into the isVisited function. Thanks for catching that, but it still didn't fix the main problem with the recursion.

Comment: Please update your question with your latest code, then, and share a sample input (value for `grid` and `color`?) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Another issue: I think you want to not do `count++` and instead pass `count+1` to the recursive call.

Comment: Or maybe you do want the `count++` but you also want to get a count from the recursive call? I'm a bit unclear on how this code is supposed to work... suppose you have a board like [1 1 1 1] and call this function starting at x=2, y=0. It would try either left or right first and then fail, right? (There aren't four in a row in either direction... you have to sum up the ones to the left and to the right.) Maybe you compensate for this by calling this function once for each position on the board?

Comment: I believe I can probably help you fix your code, but not unless you provide the full code (`isVisited` is missing) and a sample input that exhibits the problem. (I don't want to construct my own `grid` based on an image you shared when you could just print it out and paste it here.)

Comment: I guess it would be cleaner to just pass count+1 into the checkWin() function instead of ++'ing it and then passing it in, but I don't think it really makes a difference here. And the code isn't complete, so it doesn't only check if they are in a line. If there are 4 same colored nodes chained in anyway (diagonal, left/right, up/down), the function should return true. It starts by checking all the nodes around the starting node, and then recursively does that for all of those nodes that matched the color value it was looking for.

Comment: It does make a difference. `count++` changes the value of count, so it will be one greater the next iteration of the loop. Passing `count+1` won't modify the value of `count`. I think you probably want the latter.

Comment: Alright, I updated my code with that and also included the isVisited function. However I'm not sure how I could print out the 2d array and paste it.

Comment: What's wrong with `console.log(grid);`?

Comment: This is what console.log(grid) gives me: http://prntscr.com/fjhts1

Comment: Maybe `console.log(JSON.stringify(grid));` would be more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some working code. I tried to put your `grid` into the code.

There were a few issues with your code, but I think the main one is that you weren't properly summing up counts. In your code, you'll run into this situation:

```
  starting here
    |
    v
R R R R
```

You'll first explore to the left of this node, and you'll find there aren't four reds in a row. Then you'll explore to the right and find there aren't four reds in a row. But what you need to do is *sum* these. You need to count the starting node and then the two to the left and then the two to the right to get the correct total of four in a row.

The code below takes that strategy. It's a bit of a rewrite, but I tried to keep it somewhat similar to your original code. Let me know if it's unclear. (This code, like yours, doesn't really care about "in a row" but simply "touching.")

```js
const N = null, B = "black", R = "red";
const grid = [
//   0  1  2  3  4  5  6
    [N, N, N, N, N, N, N],  // 0
    [N, N, N, N, N, N, N],  // 1
    [N, N, N, N, N, N, N],  // 2
    [N, N, N, N, N, B, R],  // 3
    [N, N, N, N, B, B, R],  // 4
    [N, N, N, B, R, B, R],  // 5
];

function isVisited(x, y, visited) {
    var pointStr = [x, y].join();
    return visited.some(function (e) {
        return e.join() == pointStr;
    });
}

function checkWin(x, y) {
    function countNeighbors(x, y, color, visited) {
        if (y > 5 || x > 6) {  // out of bounds
            return 0;
        }

        if (isVisited(x, y, visited)) {  // already visited
            return 0;
        }
        visited.push([x, y]);

        if (grid[y][x] !== color) {  // wrong color
            return 0;
        }

        var count = 1;  // Count ourselves first.

        // For each neighbor,
        for (var i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
            for (var j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
                // add the count starting at that neighbor.
                count += countNeighbors(x+i, y+j, color, visited);
            }
        }

        // Return the total found.
        return count;
    }

    // There's a win if the count is at least four.
    return countNeighbors(x, y, grid[y][x], []) >= 4;
}

console.log(checkWin(3, 5));  // true
console.log(checkWin(5, 3));  // true
console.log(checkWin(6, 3));  // false
```

Comment: FYI, my grid is probably 90º rotated from yours. (You used `grid[x][y]` while I'm using `grid[y][x]`, so you're probably storing your grid differently. I did it this way because it makes it more natural to write out the grid in code.)

Comment: This makes much more sense! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing the wrong grid cell index to the `visited` list. It should be `[x + i, y + j]`.

Or, you could move the statement to the top of the function and keep it as is, which is better in my opinion. The function itself checks a cell, and it makes more sense to mark that cell as checked or visited at the start itself.

Comment: I think the latter suggestion is better, but that part of the code seems okay to me as-is. (It's just wasteful since it adds the node repeatedly to the `visited` list.)